# Method for changing values

Tags: java

I have the class "Buyer" and the class "Address", i have a constructor in Address where i can type in the information, and I also have a method to CHANGE the info. So in my class Buyer i have a constructor where i can give the buyer a name and also create an Address object, but then i tried to create a method in "Buyer" to change the value of the object from class Address, but it isn't working as it is meant to. Thank's for the help.

Essencial part of the class Address

```
    public class Address{
        private String street;

    public Address(){
            Keyboard k = new Keyboard();
            Street = k.readString("Type in the Street: ");
    }
 public void change(){
        Keyboard k = new Keyboard();
        String str;
System.out.println("If you do not wish to change the street, please just press enter.");
        str = k.readString("type in the Street: ");
            if (log.equals(""))
                str = str;
            else
                street = str;
}
```

THEN i tried doing the same thing in Buyer

```
public class Buyer{
    private String name;
    private Address address;

public buyer(String nm){
        name = nm;
        this.address = new Address();
}
public void changeAdress(){
        new Address().change();

    }
```

Comment: What is Street = k.readString("Type in the Street: ");? street should be in lower case.

Comment: I am doing this for college, i just started there and when we program in java we use a class called "Keyboard" to type in the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void changeAdress(){
        new Address().change();    
    }
```

is not right.

Your code should look like this :

Address class

```
public class Address{
        private String street;

public Address(){
            Keyboard k = new Keyboard();
            street = k.readString("Type in the Street: ");
}
public void change(){
        Keyboard k = new Keyboard();
        String str = "";
        System.out.println("If you do not wish to change the street, please just press enter.");
        str = k.readString("type in the Street: ");
            if (log.equals(""))
                str = str;
            else
                street = str;
}
}
```

Buyer class

```
public class Buyer{
    private String name;
    private Address address;

public Buyer(String nm){
        name = nm;
        address = new Address();
}
public void changeAdress(){
           address.change();   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your new address equal to Address().change:

```
public void changeAddress() {
     address = (new Address()).change();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude, but now i get the following message when compiling: "incompatible types referring to "()" from "change()"

Comment: I just made an edit that I think should fix that.  You need parentheses around the part where you're creating the new object or else it doesn't understand that you are creating a new object and then calling one of its methods

Answer (score 0):

Here you create a new instance of `Address` class and change its field.

```
 public void changeAdress(){
    new Address().change();
}
```

Instead change it for `address.change()`